# unable to update PostgreSQL table value with R's sys.time as a character using dbconnect

Tags: r, postgresql, sql-update

i am using the below code for connecting to PostgreSQL from R.

```
library(DBI)
con <- dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(),dbname = 'postgres', 
         host = host_name, 
         port = 5432, 
         user = user_name,
         password = password)
```

by using the above connection i tried to update the PostgreSQL table with sys.time() in R as character.

For that i am sending the below query to database.

```
dbSendQuery(con,paste0("update job_status set start_dttm=",as.character(sys.time()) ," where job_name='job';"))
```

but it throws the following error for me

```
Failed to prepare query: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "04"
LINE 1: update job_status set start_dttm = 2019-03-04 04:50:12 where...
```

Can anyone help me to tackle this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In postgresql we need to first specify schema name then table name ( ex schemaname.tablename.)

Comment: i tried but it throws same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Valid SQL requires quotes around the date:

```
update job_status set start_dttm='2019-03-04 04:50:12';
```

Therefore, you would need

```
paste0("update job_status set start_dttm='", as.character(sys.time(), "';")
```

---

The above query is safe from SQL injection since `sys.time()` should be safe.
However, in general (and especially when arguments are derived from user input), it is best
to [use parametrized SQL to avoid SQL injection](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/sql-injections.html).